# CRON command with Yii

Tags: php, yii, cron

I have a code that will automatic create a sitemap.xml . My Url look like this : http://example.com/sitemap

But now I want it to automatic run every minutes (just test) . I tried 2 way but none of them work :

first is call through URL ,ex:

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://example.com/sitemap
```

or

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://example.com/check
```

second is call throught php file , I'm using Yii so i'm not sure what the file .php is ? is this controller file or something else?

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/domains/public_html/protected/modules/homepage/controller/HomepageController.php
```

my Sitemap action's code inside HomepageController.php

Comment: Why don't you try to get it to do what you want with just `wget` or `curl` first and then add it to the `cron`? You definitely need to call a url, because otherwise `Yii` won't be able to route your request.

Comment: The difference between the first two and the third is, that the first to might time out because they are going through the webserver, whereas the third is only limited by the PHP max execution time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [console command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/topics.console) for running CRON calls. For example, create `SitemapCommand.php` (place it in `protected/command/`) with following code:

```
class SitemapCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function actionGenerate($debug=0)
    {
        #generating of sitemap
    }
}
```

Then add line like this, to your `crontab` file:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/domains/public_html/protected/yiic.php sitemap generate
```

Comment: Can you review [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24570233/1469208)? I'm looking at the example you have (what should be put to `crontab`) and you both use `yiic` in `protected` folder and you don't specify extra path to `index.php` entry script. How does this even work? :] According to [message displayed by `yiic help shell`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24570233/1469208) I should either move `yiic` to the same folder, where my `index.php` is placed or use `entry-script` flag to point `yiic` there. You don't do any of these things in your example. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok thanks you . I try write new code base on your example and it work for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to put something like this in your linux cron tab->

```
http://www.Yourwebstieaddress.com/index.php (use one spacebar) Controller_name (use one spacebar) function_name
```

it will definitely work

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I'm pretty sure, that console commands should be used for CRON. So Konstantin's answers seems better.