# Where should I place my app's yiic file to execute console commands?

Tags: yii, console-application

When you generate Yii 1.x auto-generated application, app's private `yiic` is placed in `protected` folder. However, when I use it to execute `yiic help shell`, I see following message:

```
It is recommended that you execute this command under
the directory that contains the entry script file of
the Web application.
```

And then:

```
* entry-script | config-file: optional, the path to
the entry script file or the configuration file for
the Web application. If not given, it is assumed to be
the 'index.php' file under the current directory.
```

What am I missing? The `protected` folder **is not** the same folder as entry script's one (`index.php`). Should I move my `yiic` there for the purpose of executing console commands?

If yes, then why `yiic` is placed `protected` folder by default, not there, where entry script is?

If not, then why `yiic` assumes, that `index.php` exists in the same folder as `yiic` itself and why do I have to change this every time with using `entry-script` flag? This just doesn't make any sense!

I think, the answer is to keep `yiic` in `protected` folder, which is secured from web access by `.htaccess` file. Entry script's folder is not secured that way and is web accessible. I would personally be very worried about moving `yiic` to root folder, where `index.php` file exists. If this is the correct answer, then what is the purpose of this confusing message, cited above?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570242/1469208) seems to be supporting my idea, as it shows that CRON call should point to `yiic` placed in `protected` folder, not to the one in root folder.

Why Yii developers put `yiic`, where it is not supposed to be (it is looking for `index.php` in the same folder, so in default auto-generated application, it will fail, not finding it)? How should I understand this situation? Why I'm forced to use extra flag every time? Why default folder structure and file placement does not replicate, what `yiic` assumes as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the help message means is that you should execute the yiic command from the WebRoot folder (where your index.php is) like so:

```
% cd WebRoot
% YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell
```

So yii will take automatically your index.php file to do its things...
But if you want to call another file like index-test.php to get yii executed instead of the default index.php you can:

```
% cd WebRoot
% YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell index-test.php
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console